# javascript: define a variable if it doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, variables

i feel like im trying to do something super simple, but just being stupid about it.

all i want to do is see if a variable has been set previously, and if it has NOT, set it with a default value....here is a sample:

```
if(!embed_BackgroundColor) {
    var embed_BackgroundColor;
    embed_BackgroundColor = "#F4F4F4";
}
```

so, once you stop laughing at my code....WHY is it overwriting the variable no matter what?

please save my nerves;)

Answer (score 83, accepted):

```
if (typeof variable === 'undefined') {
    // variable is undefined
    // eg:
    // var variable = "someValue";
}
```

Comment: the problem is that no matter what the // var variable = "someValue" is overwriting the pre-defined value that DID exist

Comment: is that really three =s?  (i don't know)

Comment: I'm not sure why this is accepted.  It seems using the code above (with the `var variable = "someValue";` line uncommented results in `variable` always being equal to "someValue" even if it was already defined.

Comment: @Mike if it was already defined, you would not get into the if condition.

Comment: @pedz it doesn't matter because the 'var' keyword will make the variable inside the if get redefined even if it never enters the if block. JS doesn't have a "block level scope variable definition".

Comment: @xDaizu declaration is hoisted but initialization/assignment is not. AFAIK repeated declaration doesn't have any negative side effects. https://jsbin.com/bibuneseno/edit?js,console,output

Answer (score 108):

Pro style:

```
var SomeVar = SomeVar || 'Default Value';
```

Comment: :\ Does this not reassign `SomeVar` to itself? Indeed it looks like a "pro" style, but it does - in fact - appear to be somewhat un-optimized (esp. for a for/while loop). I would just stick with an if. However, I could be wrong and the interpreter might recognize that it doesn't need to store a `var` back into *itself*.

Comment: A word of warning: If `SomeVar` can be a false-y value, this will fail.
Things like `''`, `false`, and `0` will trip the `||` and set the default

If you want `SomeVar` to be able to be 'false-y' values, then use a ternary, like in @Jhuni answer (but with the var keyword like in this one).

Also agree with @dylnmc, this results in unnessary reassignment. 

@Paolo Berantino has what i feel is the 'correct' answer. I personally strongly disagree that "small and compact" is nessarily 'Pro Style'.

We don't use punchcards anymore, and js minifiers equalize the rest.

Comment: Using this approach I receive  `Uncaught ReferenceError: my_var is not defined` (Chrome -v 48.0)

Comment: This is not very verbose. A new programmer would not be able to immediately decode what happens. I would not recommend this.

Comment: This the wrong answer and a "pro" would certainly not do this due to the issues mentioned by @Fodagus. Also I suspect it might not work in some JS engines, with certain strict settings or linters since it's assigning a value that potentially does not exist (which could be the issue of @popas). Just use the proper way which is `typeof Somevar === 'undefined'` to avoid all these problems.

Comment: Just realized that this question raises (yet another) JS caveat.
There are two types of "undefined" variables!
1. A declared variable with no value
2. A non declared variable 

This answer only catches (1)

var x;
typeof(x) === "undefined" // true
y=x+1; NaN

typeof(neverDeclared) === "undefined" // true
y=neverDeclared+1 // ReferenceError: neverDeclared is not defined

Comment: If you are using modern JavaScript you should use the Nullish coalescing operator (??) instead of "||"

Comment: I remember seeing it all the way back in '00s for the first time, and after figuring out what it does, actually thinking it is a *pro style*. Ah, the good old [#vectorheart](https://twitter.com/vectorheart) days. I think for a quick test against a variable that shouldn't be false-y, this will work fine. Thumbs up!

Answer (score 55):

It would be a good coding practice in this case to use the ternary operator. Also you don't need to have three equal signs when comparing with typeof. This is the most concise solution:

```
b = typeof(b) == 'undefined' ? 0 : b;
```

This hopefully will save your hands some time.

Comment: Similar to the comment on `calmbird`'s response (below ... maybe), it looks like b is being reassigned to itself when it is defined. That seems like it could be bad-ish (not terrible) in a loop. Again, I don't know how the interpreter will deal with this exactly, but it looks like it will be an unnecessary reassignment.

Comment: I thinks must use `===` instead of `==`

Comment: Should be accepted answer as it does not do _dirty_ equality checking

Comment: Sadly your answer is not entirely true, as double equa sign means the inter[reter will automatically try type conversion. Using `a === b` will always be faster, as the values are strictly compared, ommiting one step.

Comment: Technically correct and also multiple examples of poor style, right down to the single-char variable name and lack of declaration. Just wow.

Answer (score 33):

To actually answer your question of WHY this is happening, it is because of [variable hoisting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528320/javascript-variable-scope-question).

Basically, there is a phase before executing code in the global scope or inside a function where the code is scanned for all `var` and `function` declarations (not to be confused with function *expressions*, but that's a different story).
All these variable and functions are then declared inside the current scope, and *only afterwards* does the code actually run.

This happens regardless of their position in the code, with scopes corresponding to function bodies, not blocks of statements. And what makes this even more counter-intuitive, even if you set an initial value to variables in their declarations, [they will still remain "empty" until the declaration is reached again in normal execution flow](http://wtfjs.com/2010/02/15/hoisting).

So when you write:

```
if(!embed_BackgroundColor) {
    var embed_BackgroundColor;
    embed_BackgroundColor = "#F4F4F4";
}
```

what actually happens is this:

1. Code is scanned for `var` declarations. `embed_BackgroundColor` is declared inside this scope, regardless of whether it was already declared or not. Its initial value is undefined.
2. Execution of the code begins. The `if` statement is run. The variable *is* declared, but its value is undefined, so the condition is true. Using `typeof` wouldn't help you distinguish here between an undeclared and a declared-but-not-yet-set variable. It makes no difference anyway.
3. The `var` declaration is reached by normal flow of the code. If you had given the variable an initial value it would have been set now. In this case nothing happens.
4. `embed_BackgroundColor` is set to the value `"#F4F4F4"`.

So, bottom-line is: you can use `typeof variable == 'undefined'` as seen in the other answers, or even plain '!variable' as you were initially using, but don't use `var` or that will ruin everything.

Comment: Is it really in a state of being declared but evaluates as "undefined"? I thought the whole purpose of undefined was for things that are not declared! (ie. not defined). Do you mean null?

Comment: @Moss No, it really is `undefined`. It's the default for uninitialized variables in JS (by uninitialized I mean "without a value assigned to them"). Just try it on Firebug or whatever: `typeof blah` will evaluate to the string `'undefined'`.

Answer (score 13):

If it's a global variable, I like doing:

```
var defineMe = window.defineMe || 'I will define you now';
```

It's important to use the window namespace since referencing undefined variables will cause very bad errors, but referencing undefined properties will not.

Comment: Because the definition `var defineMe` gets hoisted, I don't think you need to use `window.` to access `defineMe`, even if it wasn't defined earlier. 
However, not that if defineMe is falsey (0, false, "") it will be assigned the default value. To avoid it check `typeof defineMe==='undefined'` instead

Answer (score 10):

I prefer this syntax:

`embed_BackgroundColor = embed_BackgroundColor || "#F4F4F4"`

Can't get much more simple than that! And it seems to work even if it has been var'd.

Comment: ```ReferenceError: embed_BackgroundColor is not defined``` Need to define ```var embed_BackgroundColor ``` first

Answer (score 2):

Best option:

```js
if (typeof someVar === 'undefined') someVar = someValue;
```

Comment: You might explain _why_ this is the best option. In my case I still get an error.

Answer (score 1):

If embed_BackgroundColor is a parameter in a function that didn't get passed, you can set a default with

```
embed_BackgroundColor ? embedBackgroundColor : embed_BackgroundColor = "#F4F4F4";
```

Full function example

```
function colorFunctionThing(embed_BackgroundColor) {
  embed_BackgroundColor ? embed_BackgroundColor : embed_BackgroundColor = "#F4F4F4";
  console.log(embed_BackgroundColor);
};
colorFunctionThing();
```

Outputs

```
#F4F4F4
```

Not exactly what you were looking for but still really good to know.

Answer (score 1):

As of ES2020 you can now use the nullish coalescing operator `??`. This avoids reassigning falsy values to the default value.

`var embed_BackgroundColor = embed_BackgroundColor ?? "#F4F4F4"`

Note that if you are doing a oneliner like this you need to use `var`; `let` and `const` won't let you do it in one line.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator

Answer (score 1):

Cleanest way in 2022 ECMA syntax!

If you want to overwrite "nullish" values (see ref below), assign using `let might_exist ||= default` or pass value with `(might_exist || default)`. (The parentheses are only there for clarity and to avoid operator precedence problems, delete if you'd rather.)

If you want to keep "nullish" values, assign using `let might_exist ??= default` or pass value with `(might_exist ?? default)`.

On being nullish: `??` will only overwrite `null` and `undefined`, whereas `||` will also overwrite "nullish" values like `''` and `0`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR_assignment

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment

Comment: It's confusing to refer to _'"nullish" values like `''` and `0`'_ when the "nullish" in the "nullish assignment" to which you refer expliclty means **only** `null` and `undefined` **not** those other _false-y_ values.

Answer (score 1):

As of ES2021 you can use, [Logical Assignment Operators](https://tc39.es/ecma262/2021/) that looks like this.

```
embed_BackgroundColor ||= "#F4F4F4";
```

This is setup does the same as the following code but is shorter and reduces redundancy.

```
embed_BackgroundColor = embed_BackgroundColor || "#F4F4F4"
```

This syntax also works for other logical operators like `&&` and `??`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your posted code should work. Unless your original value is 0.

The problem is somewhere else.

I'm guessing you defined 'embed_BackgroundColor' out of the scope of your code. And when you run your code, that variable is undefined with in the scope of your code, and will be assigned the default value.

Here is an example:

```
var embed_BackgroundColor = "#FF0000";

(function(){
  if(!embed_BackgroundColor) {
    var embed_BackgroundColor;
    embed_BackgroundColor = "#F4F4F4";
  }
  alert(embed_BackgroundColor); // will give you #F4F4F4
})();

alert(embed_BackgroundColor); // will give you #FF0000;
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer a general solution in PHP-like style:

`function isset(x)
{ return typeof(x)!='undefined'; }`

Comment: this won't work. It'll give you a reference error: [x] is not defined.

Comment: It works, but you need to remember, that isset(obj.arr[x]) won't work if you don't check first for isset(obj) and then isset(obj.arr).

Answer (score 0):

I follow Chris West's blog and saw that he posted a pretty cool way at http://gotochriswest.com/blog/2012/07/02/javascript-define-if-undefined/.

Basically, you have the definition for the `define` function and then use it like this:

```
define("embed_BackgroundColor", "#F4F4F4");
```

The above code will define enbed_BackgroundColor in the global context if it is not already defined.  The example that Chris used is a bit more useful and is as follows:

```
alert("jStuff is " + (typeof jStuff == "undefined" ? "un" : "") + "defined.");

define("jStuff.alert", function(msg) {
  alert(msg);
  return msg;
});

alert("jStuff is " + (typeof jStuff == "undefined" ? "un" : "") + "defined.");

var str = jStuff.alert("Show and save this message.");
```

- The first alert statement will display, "jStuff is undefined."
- The second alert statement will display, "jStuff is defined."
- The final alert statement will display the specified alert and then that string will be stored in the `str` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Because your `if` block will execute if `embed_BackgroundColor` is `false`, `0`, `""`, `null`, `undefined`, or `NaN`.

But `embed_BackgroundColor` should not be overwritten if it has already been assigned to another **non-empty string**... Or at least, it doesn't on my end.

Perhaps it is a case of conflicting scopes, as Aaron Qian has pointed out.

Answer (score -3):

```
if(embed_BackgroundColor == "" || embed_BackgroundColor == 'undefined' || embed_BackgroundColor == null){
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.