# variables and function scope in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this piece of code

```
var a = 5;
function woot(){
    console.log(a);
    var a = 6;
    function test(){ console.log(a);}
    test();
  };
woot();
```

i'm expecting 5 and 6 as an output, but i've got undefined and 6 instead.

Any thoughts?.

Comment: First thought: I hadn't expected `5`. What are you asking for? Do you need it to be `5`?

Comment: Yes, in the tutorial that i'm working on, it should be 5, but when i tried it, it gives undefined.

Comment: Can you show/link that tutorial please? If it tells you there should be a 5, it is wrong.

Comment: This is a classic demonstration of variable hoisting. I think you may be misunderstanding the tutorial.

Comment: It's smashing node book.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does shadowed variable evaluate to undefined when defined in outside scope?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528320/why-does-shadowed-variable-evaluate-to-undefined-when-defined-in-outside-scope)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variable declarations are *hoisted* to the top of the scope in which they appear. Your code is interpreted like this:

```
var a; // Outer scope, currently undefined
a = 5; // Outer scope, set to 5

function woot(){ // Function declaration, introduces a new scope
    var a; // Inner scope, currently undefined
    console.log(a); // Refers to inner scope 'a'
    a = 6; // Inner scope, set to 6
    function test(){ console.log(a);} // Refers to inner scope 'a' (now 6)
    test();
  };
woot();
```

When you declare a variable inside a function, that variable will *shadow* any variable with the same identifier that has been declared in an ancestor scope. In your example, you declare `a` in the global scope. You then declare another variable with the same identifier in the scope of the `woot` function. This variable shadows the `a` that you declared in the global scope.

Comment: I can't understand the difference, and what's the meaning of hoisted??. Besides, it still gives undefined

Comment: @user2224801: It means that the `var a` inside `woot` *shadows* (supercedes) the global variable `a` with a local variable `a`, even before the `var` line. The `var` line is lifted ["hoisted"] to the top of the function where it appears, as James shows in his rewrite. But it's only the declaration, not the initialization, that is hoisted, so when a variable is declared with `var`, its initial value is `undefined`, and it only gets another value as of an assignment (or initialization). More: [*Poor, misunderstood `var`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/poor-misunderstood-var.html)

Comment: ahaaaa, so if i removed var a from the woot, this will solve the problem.

Comment: @Fadwa - Yes, if you remove `var` from the `var a` inside `woot` you will no longer shadow the outer `a` so any reference to `a` in there will be referring to the `a` you declared outside `woot`.

Comment: got it, The var statement defines a variable within the current scope (all of it, not just "from here on").

Comment: @Fadwa - yes, that is what we mean by "hoisting".

Answer (score 0):

The [variable declaration (`var` keyword)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) is *hoisted* in the scope of your `woot` function, making it a local variable (shadowing the global variable `a`). It will be initialised as `undefined`, and return that value until you assign to it.

Answer (score 0):

at the time of:

```
function woot(){
console.log(a);
```

..the `a` doesnt exist yet! if you want to use the outer `a` you need to call it like:

```
console.log( window.a );
```

Remove the `a` you have already in function and you can use, relaxed now, that `console.log(a);` which will refer to outer one (since there's no in your function anymore)

Otherwise, use `console.log( window.a );` to differentiate the two `alphas`.